# Почему классификатор SVM выдает недвоичные значения предсказания?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Хочу получить бинарное предсказание на выходе.

Подскажите, почему выдает значения отличные от 0 и 1?

```
df_train
df_test
```

> 4000 rows × 80 columns и
> 1000 rows × 80 columns

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
poly_kernel_svm = SVC(kernel="poly")
poly_kernel_svm.fit(df_train.drop(['cl_id'], axis=1), df_train['cl_id'])
y_pred_poly_kernel = poly_kernel_svm.predict(df_test.drop(['cl_id'], axis=1))
y_pred_poly_kernel
```

```
array([ 7415,  1100,  6917,  9925,  6261,  9066,   722,  5650,  9565,
        7721,  5224,  9509,  2493,   789,  9619,   545,  8337,  1665,
        1441,  5082,  3366,  3956,  7862,  2260,    91,  4382,  2878,
        9780,  6483,  5781,  4292,  2752,  3487,   903,  9780,  7715,
        5729,  4260,  6984,  7345,  8552,  3228,  8553,  2285,  6709,
        3351,  5798,  3228,  4382,  9241,  3448,  4747....
```

Полный код [выложил на GITHUB](https://github.com/Sergey-Kit/Feature_Engineering_Cases/blob/main/Rosbank_WOE_Features_SVM.ipynb).

Comment: какие у вас значения в `cl_id` ?

Comment: и причем здесь __бинарная__ классификация?? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы обучаете модель на целевых значениях в столбце `cl_id`, которые, судя по всему, имеют совсем не бинарную природу. Поэтому и во время предсказания вы получаете похожие значения.

Comment: Разобрался! Целевая переменная - ['target_flag'], перепутал с cl_id. Спасибо!